# Systemd dropping random pieces of stdout

Tags: python, ubuntu, unix, logging, systemd

Journalctl seems to be skipping some of the output of the process the corresponding service is outputting. How is that happening?

Here's a small example: I've got the following script called `tester.py`

```
import time
count = 0
while True:
    time.sleep(.001)
    count += 1
    print count
```

And I have the following service called `tester.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=lots of output
After=network.target

[Service]
User=django
Group=django
WorkingDirectory=/home/django
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python -u tester.py
Restart=always
RestartSec=3

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After running `sudo systemctl start tester` and waiting a couple of seconds, I then run `sudo journalctl -u tester`.

I notice that the output skips large chunks of numbers. For example, here's an excerpt:

```
Oct 05 23:44:00 staging python[23185]: 999
Oct 05 23:44:00 staging python[23185]: 1000
Oct 05 23:44:00 staging python[23185]: 1001
Oct 05 23:44:29 staging python[23185]: 26829
Oct 05 23:44:29 staging python[23185]: 26830
Oct 05 23:44:29 staging python[23185]: 26831
Oct 05 23:44:29 staging python[23185]: 26832
Oct 05 23:44:29 staging python[23185]: 26833
```

Comment: Include the version of `systemd` you are using.

Comment: If you look at the full `journalctl` output, are the gaps there as well?

Comment: Oh my gosh, it's being rate limited! journalctl without any arguments shows `Suppressed xxx messages from /system.slice/tester.service`.. the default is 1000 messages per 30s. Thanks @MarkStosberg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Systemd is rate limiting your output! The default is 1000 lines of output for 30s. You can change this in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`

You can verify this is the problem by running `journalctl` by itself. You'll be seeing messages of the form `Suppressed xxx messages from /system.slice/tester.service`